# Not able to log out

Tags: php, session, logout, logoff

I work on a tool where the logout functionality is no working. I have an index page, where I include the config file with the session_start().

After, I include a page where I have my banner and my logon and logoff button. When I click on one of these button I go on another page `connec.php`, I destroy or create the connection.

The connection is okay, I initialize all my session variables.
For the disconnection I do:

```
if(isset($_POST['logout'])){
    $_SESSION = array ();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    $_POST['logout']=1; 
    //gotopage($GLOBALS["GLOBAL_URL_PSISITE"]);
    header("Location: ../index.php");
```

I'm still connected, and when I do `print_r($_SESSION)` always exist.

Comment: In your deconnexion script, make sure that you use session_start(); at the top.

Comment: Yes I use session_start() at the top.

Answer (score 2):

First of all be sure that the page has `session_start()` defined at the very top, before you do anything on the page, secondly make sure your input field is wrapped around `form` element and your `submit button` has `name=logout` and your form is set to  `method=post`

```
<form method="post" action="your_logout_script_page.php">
  <input type="submit" name="logout" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yes these thnigs are OK. Thanks

Comment: There's nothing else, or else you are missing something real simple

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like this in your file

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['logout'])) {

    $_SESSION = array();

    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000, '/');
    }

    session_destroy();

    //$_POST['logout']=1;  // this won't do anything since you're redirecting on the next line.

    header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit;

}
?>
```

Comment: @user1789039 The PHP Session ID is (usually) stored in a cookie. [As you can see in this screenshot](http://snag.gy/dGizN.jpg). It has nothing to do with you using setcookie in your code. The code above ensures it gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In order to correctly "destroy" a running session, you must first tell PHP which session you are trying to kill.

In the case of your session not having a custom/manual name (most cases), you must FIRST call

```
session_start();
```

before you can call

```
session_destroy();
```

... So:

```
<?php session_start(); session_destroy(); ?>
```